# Compiling OpenSSH on 64-bit machine with debugging symbols

Tags: debugging, gcc, compilation, symbols

I am trying to compile openssh with debugging symbols, but it is not happening and i have no idea why.

- wget "https://ftp.nluug.nl/security/OpenSSH/openssh-7.2p2.tar.gz"
- tar xfz openssh-7.2p2.tar.gz
- cd openssh-7.2p2
- autoconf
- ./configure --with-audit=debug
- make
- sudo make install
- objdump --syms bin/ssh

> bin/ssh:     file format elf64-x86-64
>
> SYMBOL TABLE: no symbols

any thoughts why the debugging symbols are not there? please note that when I execute this command as below:

```
objdump --syms bin/ssh.o
```

I can see that symbols have been added to the object file, but not in the final executable file when the linker finish up the file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you using such an old version?  The current version is 7.5p1 and includes security fixes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at what `make install` does, you'll see

```
/usr/bin/install -c -m 0755 -s ssh /usr/local/bin/ssh
```

The `-s` option causes debug symbols to be stripped, just like the `strip` command.

Maybe there's a way to disable that?

```
$ ./configure --help |grep strip
  --disable-strip         Disable calling strip(1) on install
```

Oh, there we go.